# converting a structre into query

Tags: coldfusion

i am trying to convert a small complex piece of coldfusion structure to query to use in my page:

i have the following code which i tried some conversion

```
<cfset l = "Pame=Program A&Co_Test=0&Programs2Product_ID=1
                &Product_Type_ID=1&Clients2Product_ID=422&Program_ID=1
                &S_Name=MASQW&Product_Template=BGTt&Name=MMMLD
">
<cfset q = queryNew("")>
<cfloop list="Pame,Co_Test,Programs2Product_ID,Product_Type_ID,
  Clients2Product_ID,Program_ID,S_Name,Product_Template,Name" index="k">
    <cfset queryAddColumn(q, "#k#", listToArray(listlast(l,"="),"&"))>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#q#">
```

it converts to the query, but for all columns it just adds the last vakue which is `MMMLD`

Can anyone check what i am doing wrong here

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: Given that you already have the data in what is essentially a nested list, why don't you just use it as it is and forget the query?

Comment: Why not a structure? It seems a more natural fit than a query or list. It also offers the benefit of being able to check the existence of specific keys with `structKeyExists`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `listLast()` on the variable `l`, which is the entire string, so it will always give you the last value based on the delimiter (in this case MMMLD). I got this working for me:

```
<cfset q = queryNew("")>
<cfset l = "Pame=Program A&Co_Test=0&Programs2Product_ID=1
                &Product_Type_ID=1&Clients2Product_ID=422&Program_ID=1
                &S_Name=MASQW&Product_Template=BGTt&Name=MMMLD
">

<cfset keyValueArray = listToArray(l, '&')>
<cfloop array="#keyValueArray#" index="i">
    <cfset keyValuePair = listToArray(i, '=')>
    <cfif arrayLen(keyValuePair) EQ 2>
        <cfset queryAddColumn(q, keyValuePair[1], [keyValuePair[2]])>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: (Edit-typo fix) Nothing against the answer, but it is worth noting the code above could potentially produce different results than the original depending on the query string (ie missing/extra columns or error if a parameter name occurs more than once). Seems like a structure might be more appropriate than a query here.